# Using jquery-1.7.2.min.js instead of the wordpress jquery

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, media-library

I have been trying to deregister the wordpress native jquery and use my version that i have downloaded.At first everything was working fine with the wordpress resident jquery albeit replacing `$` with `jQuery` in my `custom.js` script.

I am using media-uploader in my theme and i added the scripts using this code;

```
function wptuts_options_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'wptuts-upload', get_template_directory_uri() .'/admin/js/mlimage.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox') ); 

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
        wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');

        wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
        wp_enqueue_script('wptuts-upload');

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_options_enqueue_scripts');
```

I have this code  to add my custom jquery

```
function en_jquery()  
    {  
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );   
        wp_register_script( 'daskustomjquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' );    
        wp_enqueue_script( 'daskustomjquery' );         
    }  
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'en_jquery' );
```

Whenever i try excluding jquery from this line's array,`wp_register_script( 'wptuts-upload', get_template_directory_uri() .'/admin/js/mlimage.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox') );`

none of the scripts get loaded.Is it possible to exclude the wordpress jquery and use the `jquery-1.7.2.min` i have downloaded?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific issue is that you are registering custom jQuery version to different handle (`'daskustomjquery'`) and naturally that breaks things.

But please note that interfering with jQuery in admin is **extremely not recommended**.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.I am trying to submit a form + the submit button value using the jquery malsup form plugin.It works with jquery-1.7.2.min(a simple html file with jquery and the plugin) but fails to submit the submit button value with the wordpress jquery.

Comment: @flapjack jQuery 1.7.2 is the version WP currently includes, whatever your issue it's probably not because of the version.

Comment: Oh wow,i didn't know that.I shall look at my code harder and see what is amiss.Thanks.